# Is it possible to center a variable-width nested dropdown list to its variable width parent with only css?

Tags: drop-down-menu, centering, alignment, css

I'm making a dropdown list and the items have quite distinct lengths, so a standard width for all the items makes it look strange, however I can't get the dropdowns to behave in a way that doesn't look strange anyway. I'd like for the dropdown unordered lists to be centered to their parents but without predetermining a set width.  I've seen ways to do this with js, but wondering is there a way to acheive it just with CSS?

hhttp://jsfiddle.net/QacGj/2/

```
<div id="menu">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">parentcategory</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>

#menu
{
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}

#menu li
{
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}
#menu li a
{
 padding: 0 10px;
}
#menu li a:hover
{
 text-shadow: 0 0 15px #FFF, 0 0 15px #FFF;
}

#menu li ul
{
 border: thin #DDD solid;
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 5px 0;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width 100%
 z-index: 99999;
}
#menu li ul li 
{
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: left;
}

#menu li:hover > ul.child
{
 display: block;
}
#menu li > ul.child
{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to achieve this so, that the main link and its child popup were inside the same wrapper, with automatic margin left and right. That way they would both be centered with the same center point. Obviously ul li structure won't work that well for it, or if it does, I'm too tired to think properly :)

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/QacGj/4/